# call empty varargs method, when it is overloaded with an empty method

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Spring's [UriComponentsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.24/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html) has
an empty `build()` method, as well as variadic `build(Object... urivariables)`.

I want to call the second one with an empty array. Is there a better way to do so, then
`build(new Object[0])`?

Just calling `.build()` goes for the first.

Comment: There's no better way. However, you could hide the incantation in a helper method like `MyClass build0() {return build(new Object[0]);}`

Comment: Maybe you can try casting it to a URIBuilder.

Comment: The point is that it's a framework class and I cannot modify or extend it.

Comment: Who said anything about extending it? Cast is either assigning it to a variable of a parent type, or putting the parent type before it in `()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to call the second one with an empty array. Is there a better way to do so, than `build(new Object[0])?`

More or less 'no'. - varargs is **syntax sugar** - bytecode wise there is absolutely no difference whatsoever between:

```
void test(String... example) {}

test(new String[1] {"Hello"});
```

and

```
void test(String... example) {}

test("Hello");
```

**Both** of those examples will allocate a new 1-sized string array, sets the first (and only) string slot in that array to refer to the string `"Hello"`, and then calls the `test` method, passing a reference to the newly created array. It's just that in the second snippet, `javac` generates all that for you. (If in doubt, or to assuage curiosity, by all means play around with this and use `javap -c -v` to see the bytecode for yourself!)

Hence, calling: `build(new Object[0])` is bytecodewise **identical** to any hypothetical java construct that lets you explicitly pick the varargs overload of `build()` somehow (there is no such java construct. Point is, even if there was, it wouldn't matter).

### A sidestep into API design

Given that java methods have their identities determined by **both** their name **as well as** their parameter types, but that most humans interacting with code consider only the name, it is **really bad API design** if confusion about which of a number of overloads is relevant. In other words, if you can call a non-obvious overload and the behaviour will be meaningfully different from other overloads it could feasibly be understood to call to your average java programmer, **that is really bad API design**.

Take `System.out.println` for example. It has many overloads; `String` and `Object` are amongst them. Given that all strings are objects, it is entirely possible to call both overloads:

```
String x = "Hello";
System.out.println(x); // calls PrintStream.println(String)
Object y = x;
System.out.println(y); // calls PrintStream.println(Object)
```

The above code calls 2 completely different methods, in both cases passing the exact same object.

Fortunately, *this is simply irrelevant*, because these 2 different methods act identically when you do this. They both just print the string. Hence, which one of the two overloads is called whenever you see code that passes what you know to be a string object is an academic curiosity and nothing more.

That aspect (between a bunch of overloads it doesn't matter which one you call when passing the same data to them, they all act identically) is important to good API design.

Hence, *generally*, if there is both `foo()` as well as `foo(T... something)` in a given API, there is *no difference* between calling the no-args foo, and calling the varargs foo with an empty array (no actual arguments). If this API acts meaningfully differently, deal with it the same way you deal with any API that is horribly designed:

- Consider using something else, or at least add 1 demerit to this library (move it up on the agenda for 'this should perhaps be replaced one day').
- Grit your teeth and deal with it. Or...
- Write a wrapper that undoes the mess.

If this API does not act meaningfully differently, why do you care? Creating short-lived zero-length arrays has no measurable cost.

### One option available to you

zero-length arrays are immutable. Their state cannot possibly be changed (arrays are fixed size and given that there are zero slots you can't 'set' anything on one of them). Hence, if you must, you can make a global constant. This isn't spaghettifying your code base (that only applies to globals that have non-constant state - hence, does not apply to zero-length arrays). There is no relevant performance benefit to doing this (yes, you avoid having to create zero-len arrays, but as mentioned before, small short-lived garbage isn't relevant, java GCs are designed to make that about as free as possible).

Thus, care about this only if you feel it is 'cleaner'. That this:

```
private static final Object[] NO_TEMPLATE_VALUES = new Object[0];

uriComponentsBuilder.build(NO_TEMPLATE_VALUES);
```

is more readable than:

```
uriComponentsBuilder.build(new Object[0]);
```

It probably is - generally if you're going out of your way to invoke a non-obvious overload, your code has become unreadable (after all, any reader will immediately wonder why in the blazes you are doing something so bizarre for no discernible purpose), and the code should therefore go out of its way to:

- Clarify that is not some oversight - it is very much intentional.

and preferably, also explain why you're doing it (explain in a comment what the difference is between `build()` and `build(new Object[0])` and therefore why you've jumped through all these hoops).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the `URIComponentsBuilder` as a `URIBuilder`.

The reason you would want to use the `build(Object...)` even without parameters is that it returns a `URI` rather than `URIComponents`.

But the only reason `URIComponentsBuilder` has this method is because it implements `URIBuilder`, which means you can use it as a `URIBuilder`, like this:

```
public class JustATest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UriBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://example.com/foo/bar/baz");
        builder.port(8088);
        URI uri = builder.build();
        System.out.println(uri);

    }
}
```

So in this example I am creating a builder for a certain URL then changing its port. But that doesn't matter, the point is that I am assigning the `UriComponentsBuilder` to a variable of type `UriBuilder`. As such, it only recognizes the varargs `build(Object...)`, and so you don't need to use anything as parameter.

Answer (score -1):

This

```java
uriComponentsBuilder.build(new Object[0]);
```

calls under the hood

```java
return this.buildInternal(UriComponentsBuilder.EncodingHint.ENCODE_TEMPLATE).expand(uriVariables).toUri();
```

If you want to call `this.buildInternal()` and get a URI returned you could achieve the same by calling

```java
uriComponentsBuilder.build(false).toUri();
```